How To make Responsive Carousel in MudBlazor
This is MudCarousel which has 2 MudCarouselItem and inside each MudCarouselItem it has 4 MudCards. My problem is when I view this in mobile view then MudCarouselItem's First MudCard is going visible others goes hidden unable to access or see.
  
 <MudCarousel Class="mud-width-full" Style="height:220px;" ShowArrows="true" ShowBullets="false" EnableSwipeGesture="true" AutoCycle="false" TData="object">
    <MudCarouselItem Transition="@Transition.Slide">
                 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="height:100%;">
                    <div class="carousel-container">
                        <MudGrid>
                           <MudItem xs="12" sm="3" >  
                        <MudCard Class="hover-paper paper1" Style="height: 210px;width:270px; margin-right:5px;" Elevation="4">
                            <MudCardHeader style="height: 75px; background-color:#FFF176; text-align:center;">
                                <CardHeaderContent>
                                    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
                                        <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
                                        
                                        <MudText Typo="Typo.caption" Color="Color.Dark" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                                              Application Name 1
                                        </MudText>
                                        </div>
                                        <MudTooltip Text="Name of IT Owners/Business" Arrow="true" Placement="Placement.Top">
                                            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Help" Size="Size.Small" />
                                        </MudTooltip>
                                    </div>
                                </CardHeaderContent>
                    </MudCardHeader>
                <MudCardContent style="margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0;word-wrap: break-word;font-size:small;" >
                  
                    </MudCardContent>
                    <MudCardActions></MudCardActions>
                </MudCard>
                    </MudItem>
                    <MudItem xs="12" sm="3">
                        <MudCard Class="hover-paper paper2" Style="height: 210px;width:270px;margin-right:5px;" Elevation="4">
                            <MudCardHeader style="height: 75px; background-color:#F8BBD0;;text-align:center;">
                        <CardHeaderContent>
                                    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
                                        <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
                                            
                                        <MudText Typo="Typo.caption" Color="Color.Dark" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                                               Application Name 2
                                        </MudText>
                                        </div>
                                        <MudTooltip Text="Name of IT Owners/Business" Arrow="true" Placement="Placement.Top">
                                            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Help" Size="Size.Small" />
                                        </MudTooltip>
                                    </div>
                        </CardHeaderContent>
                    </MudCardHeader>
                            <MudCardContent style="margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0;word-wrap: break-word;font-size:small;">
                        
                    </MudCardContent>
                </MudCard>
                </MudItem>
                 <MudItem xs="12" sm="3" >  
                        <MudCard Class="hover-paper paper3" Style="height: 210px;width:270px; margin-right:5px;" Elevation="4">
                            <MudCardHeader style="height: 75px; background-color:#B3E5FC;text-align:center;">
                        <CardHeaderContent>
                                    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
                                        <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
                                            <MudText Typo="Typo.caption" Color="Color.Dark" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                                                  Application Name 3
                                            </MudText>
                                        </div>
                                        <MudTooltip Text="Name of IT Owners/Business" Arrow="true" Placement="Placement.Top">
                                            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Help" Size="Size.Small" />
                                        </MudTooltip>
                                    </div>
                        </CardHeaderContent>
                    </MudCardHeader>
                            <MudCardContent style="margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0;word-wrap: break-word;font-size:small;">
                        
                    </MudCardContent>
                </MudCard>
                </MudItem>
                 <MudItem xs="12" sm="3" >  
                        <MudCard Class="hover-paper paper4" Style="height: 210px;width:270px; margin-right:5px;" Elevation="4">
                            <MudCardHeader style="height: 75px; background-color:#AED581 ;text-align:center;">
                        <CardHeaderContent>
                                    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
                                        <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
                                            <MudText Typo="Typo.caption" Color="Color.Dark" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                                                  Application Name 4
                                            </MudText>
                                        </div>
                                        <MudTooltip Text="Name of IT Owners/Business" Arrow="true" Placement="Placement.Top">
                                            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Help" Size="Size.Small" />
                                        </MudTooltip>
                                    </div>
                        </CardHeaderContent>
                    </MudCardHeader>
                            <MudCardContent style="margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0;word-wrap: break-word;font-size:small;">
                       
                    </MudCardContent>
                </MudCard>
                </MudItem>
                 </MudGrid>
                </div>
            </div> 
    </MudCarouselItem>
    <MudCarouselItem Transition="@Transition.Slide">
           <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="height:100%;">
                    <div class="carousel-container">
                           <MudGrid>
                           <MudItem xs="12" sm="3" > 
                    <MudCard Class="hover-paper paper1" Style="height: 210px;width:250px; margin-right:5px;" Elevation="4">
                            <MudCardHeader style="height: 75px;background-color:#FFF176;;text-align:center;">
                    <CardHeaderContent>
                           <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
                                        <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
                                         
                                        <MudText Typo="Typo.caption" Color="Color.Dark" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                                             Application Name 5
                                        </MudText>
                                        </div>
                                        <MudTooltip Text="Name of IT Owners/Business" Arrow="true" Placement="Placement.Top">
                                            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Help" Size="Size.Small" />
                                        </MudTooltip>
                                    </div>
                    </CardHeaderContent>
                </MudCardHeader>
                            <MudCardContent style="margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0;word-wrap: break-word;">
                    
                </MudCardContent>
            </MudCard>
                           </MudItem>
                            <MudItem xs="12" sm="3" > 
                    <MudCard Class="hover-paper paper2" Style="height: 210px;width:250px; margin-right:5px;" Elevation="4">
                            <MudCardHeader style="height: 75px;background-color:#F8BBD0;text-align:center;">
                    <CardHeaderContent>
                             <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
                                        <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
                                         
                                        <MudText Typo="Typo.caption" Color="Color.Dark" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                                              Application Name 6
                                        </MudText>
                                        </div>
                                        <MudTooltip Text="Name of IT Owners/Business" Arrow="true" Placement="Placement.Top">
                                            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Help" Size="Size.Small" />
                                        </MudTooltip>
                             </div>
                    </CardHeaderContent>
                </MudCardHeader>
                            <MudCardContent style="margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0;word-wrap: break-word;">
                   
                </MudCardContent>
            </MudCard>  </MudItem>
                            <MudItem xs="12" sm="3" > 
                    <MudCard Class="hover-paper paper3" Style="height: 210px;width:250px; margin-right:5px;" Elevation="4">
                            <MudCardHeader style="height: 75px;background-color:#B3E5FC;text-align:center;">
                            <CardHeaderContent>
                                     <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
                                        <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
                                        
                                        <MudText Typo="Typo.caption" Color="Color.Dark" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                                              Application Name 7
                                        </MudText>
                                        </div>
                                        <MudTooltip Text="Name of IT Owners/Business" Arrow="true" Placement="Placement.Top">
                                            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Help" Size="Size.Small" />
                                        </MudTooltip>
                                    </div>
                            </CardHeaderContent>
                        </MudCardHeader>
                            <MudCardContent style="margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0;word-wrap: break-word;">
                            
                        </MudCardContent>
                    </MudCard>
                      </MudItem>
                            <MudItem xs="12" sm="3" > 
                        <MudCard Class="hover-paper paper4" Style="height: 210px;width:250px; margin-right:5px;" Elevation="4">
                            <MudCardHeader style="height: 75px;background-color:#AED581 ;text-align:center;">
                            <CardHeaderContent>
                                    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
                                        <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
                                         
                                        <MudText Typo="Typo.caption" Color="Color.Dark" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                                            Application Name 8
                                        </MudText>
                                        </div>
                                        <MudTooltip Text="Name of IT Owners/Business" Arrow="true" Placement="Placement.Top">
                                            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Help" Size="Size.Small" />
                                        </MudTooltip>
                                    </div>
                            </CardHeaderContent>
                        </MudCardHeader>
                            <MudCardContent style="margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0;word-wrap: break-word;">
                            
                        </MudCardContent>
                    </MudCard>
                            </MudItem></MudGrid>
               </div>
            </div>
            </MudCarouselItem>
        </MudCarousel>
             


In mobile view i want my Carousel to act like that it shows one mudcard and arrow click left/right it should show prevoius/Next mudcard accordingly(one Mudcard at a time). That is in Mobile View, I want to see only one Mudcard which should act like MudCarouselItem enable to access other Mudcards using Prevoius and Next arrows.
Try MudBlazor Link
Desktop View:

Mobile View:



https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cYcIuywezvstrCSi
If you execute this in "desktop" mode it should show 4 items at a time. If you change to mobile mode and execute again, it should show 1 item at a time. It will not switch between views (4 & 1) by simply expanding or shrinking the screen size.  You can add a breakpoint listener if that's required.

Video snippet
You can use the IBrowserViewportService to determine how your carousel items should be rendered. In this full code example I've added three different options for rendering based on screen size (you can modify as necessary for your needs). The main logic is shown below:
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
        
        if (!firstRender) return;

        _initialized = true;

        var breakpoint = await BrowserViewportService.GetCurrentBreakpointAsync();

        switch (breakpoint)
        {
            case Breakpoint.Xs:
            case Breakpoint.Sm:
                _itemGroups = ChunkList<TData>(Items, 1);
                break;
            case Breakpoint.Md:
                _itemGroups = ChunkList<TData>(Items, PerRow / 2);
                break;
            default:
                _itemGroups = ChunkList<TData>(Items, PerRow);
                break;
        }      

        StateHasChanged();
    }

The PerRow parameter is used to determine how much you want to display (in your case 4).
The IBrowserViewportService checks the current screen size and the switch determines how much items should be included on each carousel view.

sm & xs - 1 item per view (mobile)
md - 2 items per view (this can be removed)
default - 4 items per view (desktop)


Note: changing the screen size of the already rendered carousel will not update the number of items shown per row. The number of items is determined by the initial screen size (size of screen when page loads)


Can We  set custom view (desktop) too like for larger screen desktop like xl and xxl  by setting 'switch (breakpoint)
{
case Breakpoint.xl:
_itemGroups = ChunkList(Items, 5);
break;
case Breakpoint.xxl:
_itemGroups = ChunkList(Items, 6);
break;
}      '

Yes, you can. You can define the amount to show for each breakpoint as you wish
